# ¿Cómo elevar a una potencia a toda una ecuacion?

Tags: c++

Intento elevar a la potencia de 0.5 para toda la ecuación, pero no encuentro la manera correcta de formular lo que quiero hacer. Si alguien tiene alguna respuesta me ayudaría muchísimo, gracias.

```
#include <iostream>
// Construya un programa tal que dados los tres lados de un triangulo, 
// pueda determinar su area.


using namespace std;

int main()

{

    float L1;
    float L2;
    float L3;
    float S;
    float AREA;

    cout<< "LADO 1:";
    cin>> L1;

    cout<< "LADO 2:";
    cin>> L2;

    cout<< "LADO 3:";
    cin>> L3;

    S = (L1 + L2 + L3) / 2;
    AREA = (S * (S - L1) * (S - L2) * (S - L3)) **0.5;

    cout<< "CALCULO AUXILIAR:"<< S << endl;

    cout<< "AREA:"<< AREA << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: LADO 1:7.5
LADO 2:7.5
LADO 3:7.5
CALCULO AUXILIAR:11.25
AREA:296.631

--------------------------------
Process exited after 6.139 seconds with return value 0
Presione una tecla para continuar . . .                                                                                            No me sale el resultado que deberia dividiendolo de esa manera :,v

Comment: Te funcionó aplicando mi comentario?

Comment: Si me sale el calculo auxiliar, pero no me sale como tal el área, y probé dividiendo entre 2, por/dividiendo 0.5 y por/dividiendo 1/2, tampoco me salio.

Comment: ¡Cuidado! elevar a la 0.5 (a la 1/2) es obtener raíz cuadrada. Las potencias fraccionarias son "radicales"

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funciono con sqrt, que era lo que trataba de hacer.

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez el primer comentario que hiciste es incorrecto: **elevar un número a 0.5 no es igual a dividirlo entre dos**, es lo mismo que hacer la raíz cuadrada.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utiliza esta documentación:
[Raiz y potencia](https://lauvm.es.tl/Pseudo-a-codigo.htm)

Esta documentación muestra ejemplos de buscar la potencia y raiz en c++ pero como estas utilizando la formula de Heron para calcular el area de un triangulo debes usar sqrt.

Usa:

```
AREA = sqrt(S * (S - L1) * (S - L2) * (S - L3));
```

sqrt buscara la raíz cuadrada de tu operación.

Comment: Una respuesta de calidad no puede basarse principalmente en enlaces externos ya que si se rompen tu respuesta seria inutil para la comunidad, por ejemplo tu segundo enlace ya se ha roto. por favor lee [answer]

Comment: Gracias por la sugerencia

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta sustituyendo el enlace de referencia con una respuesta directa

Answer (score 1):

El calculo del area esta equivocado, la formula de Heron que intentas utilizar, efectivamente implica elevar tu producto a la potencia (1/2), pero como lo intentas realizar esta equivocado. Te sugiero incluir la libreria math.h y emplear la funcion "sqrt" y dejar tu codigo de la siguiente manera:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  float L1;
  float L2;
  float L3;
  float S;
  float AREA;

  cout<< "LADO 1:";
  cin>> L1;

  cout<< "LADO 2:";
  cin>> L2;

  cout<< "LADO 3:";
  cin>> L3;

  S = (L1 + L2 + L3) / 2;
  AREA = sqrt(S * (S - L1) * (S - L2) * (S - L3));

  cout<< "CALCULO AUXILIAR:"<< S << endl;

  cout<< "AREA:"<< AREA << endl;
  return 0;
}
```